# Multer file uploder is not working in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am trying to upload multi part form data using mutler but my req.body is always undefined and req.file.[fieldname] is also always undefined and multer is also not creating any folder for storage

here is my app.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app
  .use(logger('dev'))
  .use(express.json())
  .use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
  .use(cors())
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')))
  .use('/api', require('./routes'))
module.exports = app;
```

my route file

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const companyController = require('../controllers/company.controller');
const { companyFileUpload } = require('../utils/companyFileUpload.utils');

router.post(
  '/register',
  companyFileUpload.fields([
    { name: 'profilePic', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'my-files', maxCount: 10 }
  ]),
  companyController.registerComapny
);
module.exports = router;
```

Multer middlware

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.fieldname === 'certificate') {
      // if uploading resume
      cb(null, 'uploads/user/company/certificates/');
    } else if (file.fieldname === 'profilePic') {
      // else uploading image
      cb(null, 'uploads/user/company/profilePics/');
    }
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

const filefilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.fieldname === 'certificate') {
    // if uploading certificate
    if (
      file.mimetype === 'application/pdf' ||
      file.mimetype === 'application/msword' ||
      file.mimetype === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
    ) {
      // check file type to be pdf, doc, or docx
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false); // else fails
    }
  } else if (file.fieldname === 'profilePic') {
    // else uploading profile pic
    if (
      file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
      file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
      file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'
    ) {
      // check file type to be png, jpeg, or jpg
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false); // else fails
    }
  }
};

const companyFileUpload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: filefilter
});
module.exports = { companyFileUpload };
```

and my controller

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const Company = require('../models/Company');

module.exports.registerComapny = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.files['profilePic']);
  
    console.log(req.body); //undefined although I ma sending data
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 200,
      data: 'Your Account has been created. Please wait for the verification by Admin'
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('ERROR:', e);
    return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, data: e.message });
  }
};
```

My server is running I am using postman to submit form data but my images is not getting saved also folder is not creating

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of how you're making the request in Postman?

Comment: Your file filter doesn't have anything for `my-files`. I'd try removing it for now to eliminate it as a problem